# Pushwoosh, can I change how often it asks for a location update? Terrible battery life

Tags: android, push-notification, geofencing, pushwoosh

Hopefully someone here knows how to help me. I've started using the Pushwoosh SDK in my Android app and will be using their geofencing service as well. As a result I have found that my battery life as dropped a lot. My app used 86% of battery life between last night and this morning while it was basically just in standby.

I checked the logs and PushWoosh is asking for a location update every second or so which is crazy. Is there a way for me to change that every hour or maybe more?

The areas I will geofence are going to be huge so checking every second will be detrimental to my app and to the users phone.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PushWoosh send their SDKs as .jar files but after contacting them they sent me a library project of their source code and in there I am able to change the location updates to whatever I desire.

If anyone sees this, I suggest contact PushWoosh.